# Converting from UDP Datagram to UDS datagram

Tags: udp, datagram, unix-socket

I have a couple of questions regarding Unix Domain Sockets. We currently have an application that has a receiver service receiving datagram packets from multiple client processes on the same machine using the loopback address.  We want to convert it over to using Unix Domain Sockets. Here are my questions:

1. The receiver process may be down when senders are running, in UDP, the packets were just dropped. Is the behavior of UDS the same or do the senders receive an error (may also have started before the receiver and therefor the UDS path may not have been bound)?
2. The receiver may go down and be restarted. Since it has to unlink the path before binding, do the running senders packets make it to the receiver or do they need to reset?
3. If the receiver is down for an extended period, do the oldest packets get dropped or will it fill blocking the senders?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What benefit are you expecting?

Comment: Primarily for security. UDP is available to be scanned on the host whereas UDS uses UNIX file permissions.